# How to get both text and value of a dropdown from Sitecore form?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am able to get the selected value of a sitecore forms dropdown using the code below, but how can I get the selected text?

```
postedField.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
```

Comment: Sitecore 9 Form?

Comment: This is not SXA related question - removing SXA tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about Sitecore 9 Forms, if you have the value, you can get the selected text of a dropdown field like this:

```
if (field is DropDownListViewModel)
{
 DropDownListViewModel dropdownField = field as DropDownListViewModel;
 string selectedtext = dropdownField.Items.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value == value)?.Text;
}
```

By the way, the HabitatHome demo repository has a useful little extension method sample for getting the value of a submitted form field. Check it out [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Content/blob/develop/src/Feature/Forms/code/Extensions/FormFieldExtensions.cs)